# Library compatibility issue using convert

Tags: c, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading, imagemagick-convert

I'm getting a seg fault when running `convert` from the command line to combine a small number of JPG files into a PDF:

```
$ convert ./file_*.jpg  p.pdf
Segmentation fault
```

There, you see? To try to track down what's going on, I ran it under the debugger and I got the following:

```
(gdb) run ./file_*.jpg  p.pdf
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/convert ./file_*.jpg  p.pdf
warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6" is not at the expected address
warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/libpng12.so.0" is not at the expected address
warning: difference appears to be caused by prelink, adjusting expectations
warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1" is not at the expected address
```

Can anyone tell me what this means? It looks as if there's a library incompatibility, but I'm not sure exactly what or what I can do about it.

Apologies if my tags are wrong - please feel free to change if you can think of more appropriate ones. I configured and made the convert app from source so I guess I wasn't really expecting this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with `prelink` Prelink tries to speed upload time by helping the dynamic linker. See [man prelink](http://linux.die.net/man/8/prelink) for more info on what it does.  You can un-prelink an executable with the following command.

`prelink --undo /path/to/executable`

That should revert the executable to normal dynamic linking.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but got `prelink: ./convert does not have .gnu.prelink_undo section`

Comment: My only other advice then is to check to make sure all the packages are up to date.  Were they all installed with your package manager, or did you build some yourself?